# Show branch in the output of `git log -G foo`

Tags: git

How to show the branches which contain the commit in the output of `git log -G foo`?

Up to now it looks like this:

```
commit a24dc0cd5403b697634976f2f7eef4aa7af61b3d
Author: Thomas Guettler <foo@thomas-guettler.de>
Date:   Mon Aug 8 11:16:30 2022 +0200

    use timezone, and two tests for one day.

commit 8ffe418ff64b899958cf9da594852a13dc993673
Author: Thomas Guettler <foo@thomas-guettler.de>
Date:   Mon Aug 8 11:11:29 2022 +0200

    removed debug code.
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
commit a24dc0cd5403b697634976f2f7eef4aa7af61b3d
Author: Thomas Guettler <foo@thomas-guettler.de>
Date:   Mon Aug 8 11:16:30 2022 +0200
Branches: feature-foo

    use timezone, and two tests for one day.

commit 8ffe418ff64b899958cf9da594852a13dc993673
Author: Thomas Guettler <foo@thomas-guettler.de>
Date:   Mon Aug 8 11:11:29 2022 +0200
Branches: main feature-foo

    removed debug code.
```

Comment: You'd have to [write that format](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats). For the part about ouputting branches, you'll probably have to launch a sub-command to retrieve `git branch --contains <hash>`. What do you have so far?

Comment: @RomainValeri Up to now I looked at the man page and googled for a solution. I once worked with a python binding for git, so I could solve this with a script. But maybe there is already a solution which I have not found yet.

Comment: I find it somewhat regrettable that you put a bounty on this question, but did not provide any feedback to some of the people answering. Often, feedback can guide them to improve their answers and focus more precisely on what you need. You also let the grace period expire, which is kind of strange. I can only conclude that you are so happy with your own Python solution that non of this is of any interest anymore. But maybe you could have said so, then other people would have saved their own time for something else. No harm done, I am just confused.

Comment: @kriegaex yes you are right. I feel gulty. I was not available during the last days. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

git doesn't have this functionality readily available, but you can do essentially the same `git log` does by doing `git show` in every commit. The reason you would want to do it per-commit is that `git log` might take some time to find every commit, and in the meantime you can see the output of the ones already found. Also, you can use `less` and see them as you scroll.

All we have to do is add the information we want in the format of `git show` itself:

```bash
git log --format='%H' "$@" | while read -r id; do
    IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a branches < <(git branch --format='%(refname:short)' --contains "$id")
    git --no-pager show --format="commit %H%nAuthor: %an <%ae>%nDate: %ad%nBranches: ${branches[*]}%n%n%w(76,4,4)%B" --quiet "$id"
done
```

To make it a proper command you can create a binary `git-log-branches` anywhere in your `$PATH`, and then you can call it with `git log-branches`. Also, you can wrap the command inside `less < <(...)` to be paged like other `git` commands.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

less -FRX < <(
...
)
```

---

I saw kriegaex's time comparison, but it isn't realistic, the whole point of the question is to search for a regex with `-G`. If we actually do that in a real repository a good chunk of the time is spent waiting for input, and the solutions work very differently.

In a real repository with 11874 commits, doing a `-G` search returns 28 commits but it takes a while to get them all (~10s). Using a pager we don't have to wait, we can see the first commit as soon as it's available, and in that case the two solutions provide very different results from the time they are launched to the time the first commit is available:

- kriegaex: 4.688s
- felipec: 0.167s

Even when no commit limiting and no pager kriegaex's version is 11% slower.

I created a [test script](https://gist.github.com/felipec/ed96a45615bb0058563243e06fe9eb5e) which compares all the versions in a repository specifically built for this with 1000 commits.

| id | seconds | diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| felipec | 5.72 | 0% |
| felipec (original) | 5.02 | 14% |
| kriegaex | 6.44 | -11% |
| kriegaex (new) | 5.10 | 12% |

Even kriegaex's new version is not as fast as my original version. The only reason I did not submit my original version is that the code is more complicated and the advantage is not that great (only 14% faster), but here it is for reference:

```bash
while read -r -d $'\0' commit; do
    id=${commit#commit }
    id=${id%%$'\n'*}
    IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a branches < <(git branch --format='%(refname:short)' --contains "$id")
    echo -e "${commit/BRANCHES/${branches[*]}}\n"
done < <(git log --format="tformat:commit %H%nAuthor: %an <%ae>%nDate: %ad%nBranches: BRANCHES%n%n%w(76,4,4)%B%w()%x00" "$@")
```

Comment: Sorry, I disagree. The question was not about how to use `-G`, the OP already knows how to do that. The question is about how to incorporate the information which branches each commit belongs to into the log output. This is why I did not use `-G` in my answer. With many log entries, my solution is faster than yours, and I also tested in a real-world OSS project with many commits. I also wrote in my answer that, depending on what use case you have, both your solution and mine can be tweaked for performance. Yours is tweaked for `-G`, which explains the better performance - no surprise.

Comment: BTW, measuring time to find the **first** commit is one thing. I measured the time to process **all** commits - apples and pears.

Comment: This is the question: "Show branch in the output of `git log -G foo`". If you are going to ignore the only specific thing in the question, go head, but personally I believe the user wants to show the branch in the output of... `git log -G foo`.

Comment: No! The OP says that information he likes to see is missing from `git log -G foo`, the question is not about `-G`, because the same information is missing from any call to `git log`. So the question is about how to incorporate that information into the log output, which both your question and mine answer equivalently. Besides, I just tested with `-G foo` in my project, too, but I fairly measured the time to process **all** commits - and again the performance is the same with slight, but insignificant advantage for my solution, see my upcoming update.

Comment: Please also note my updated findings with a bigger repository and an explanation why we need to be careful about what we measure.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention: I do like your solution. I just want you to stop bashing mine and measuring the wrong thing. 

Comment: @kriegaex This is a false dichotomy. The user wants **both** to see the branches of every commit and the output of `git log -G foo`.

Comment: And I'm not "bashing" your solution, your solution works, but mine is better. The reason is that it takes into consideration that in real repositories it might take time to find the relevant commits, and commit limiting is one of the primary purposes of `git log`.

Comment: I concur that your solution is better with regard to pageability, because it displays results bit by bit. Mine is ~20% faster than yours with regard to overall processing time for **all** found commits. This is also true if you subtract the time `git -G` takes in the last measurement in my answer from both overall results for our two scripts. So what is "better", depends on the use case. If the user want to page the result, your solution is definitely better. If she wants better performance, mine has a slight edge. 20% is not huge, but not nothing either.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate comment, but I am not sure if your are reading the comments under my own answer: I have come up with a best-of-both-worlds solution, performing as well as my original one when measuring overall execution time for all processed commits and enabling the output to be displayed commit by commit like your solution does.

Comment: @kriegaex You are making the assumption because in **one** of your tests you saw a marginal difference that means my version is slower, this is false. In my tests your version is slower, even for a full log. I created a script to create a repository and run tests for all versions, your is 11% slower, even your new version is 1.6% slower than my original one.

Comment: I can hardly say anything intelligent about the "initial" version you decided **not** to post. All I can say is that, honestly and without cheating, the 20% performance on average across multiple projects I tested are real and not "marginal", but significant. It is also easily explained by the fact that I call Git exactly 1 time to create the log as such + (n) times for fetching the branch names. Your initially posted script calls Git another (n) times for generating the logs. I do not like your judgemental statement claiming that your solution is "better", when in fact it is just different.

Comment: I already said that in my opinion the commit filtering (`-G foo`) is an essential part of the question, therefore whatever gains you think your version has when that is **not** happening are not relevant. My original version (the one I posted) is 27 times faster presenting the first result for that case. If you want to ignore my opinion and keep claiming a marginal performance improvement for a use case nobody cares about, by all means go ahead.

Comment: You might not have noticed, but like I said, my current solution is just as `less`-friendly as yours, immediately displaying the first commit, just like your own solution. So it does not have the original disadvantage of long waiting time for the first commit anymore. It has all advantages your solution has plus the faster speed. Therefore, there is no need to dramatise in your reply, comparing 4.688s to 0.167 s or talking about "27 times faster", because it simply is not true anymore. Both time to first commit and total time are equal or faster for `-G`, even for huge real-life repositories.

Comment: The new solution you posted in your update, however - the one you call your "original version" - actually **is** faster than my new solution in total. After subtracting the time for `-G` from plain Git, your new "original" solution is faster than mine by ~25%. But it throws lots of errors like `line 7: echo: write error: No error` when calling the script with `| less` and then exiting less with "q". If you fix that as well, it is perfect. Looking forward to another update. 

Comment: @kriegaex I don't get any error. Might be something related to your shell, or bash version.

Comment: Can we sort it out together? Feel free to open my profile and contact me via one of the contact types listed there, e.g. Telegram or Gitter. This discussion has taken too much space already. My interest is to evolve your script into something that everybody can use. You helped me improve my solution by your criticism, I want to help you, too. BTW, I am using Git Bash on Windows, which I never had any compatibility issues with before. I guess it is just a detail, and you seemingly being more experienced in shall scripting (I am just so-so), you probably are going to figure it out in no time.

Comment: git version 2.29.2.windows.3, GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys), less 563 (PCRE regular expressions)

Comment: Interestingly, an upgrade to git version 2.37.3.windows.1, GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys), less 590 (PCRE regular expressions) seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

#### Updated answer

I just had a simple idea which contains both

- the performance advantage of ~20% of my original answer compared to *FelipeC*'s, avoiding to call both `git log` (once) and `git show` (for each commit), and
- the advantage of *FelipeC*'s better pageability (found commits are processed one by one, not after processing the whole output like in my original answer).

This is achieved by no longer using GNU sed's subshell execution mode but by reading the output line by line, replacing the Git hash in lines "Branches: 8ba14..." by the result of `git branch --contains 8ba14...`. In this simple solution, I do not even use sed or awk anymore, just Bash's built-in substring functionality:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

#less -FRX < <(
git --no-pager log --quiet --pretty=format:"commit %H%nAuthor:   %an <%ae>%nDate:     %ad%nBranches: %H%n%n%w(76,4,4)%B" "$@" | while read -r LINE; do
  if [ "${LINE:0:10}" = "Branches: " ]; then
    echo "Branches: $(git branch --contains ${LINE:10} --format='%(refname:short)' | tr '\n' ' ')"
  else
    echo "$LINE"
  fi
done
#)
```

Uncomment `less` paging according to your own preference. Thanks to *FelipeC* for discussing and comparing our original solutions with one another, helping me come up with this improved version.

#### Original answer

Out of the box, Git cannot embed a shell script in its pretty-format string. Here is a quick & dirty solution. It kind of mimics the format you want, but without colour and without some of the extra information Git might print in certain situations. But I hope it gives you a clue how to continue and refine it.

Preconditions:

- You use a UNIX-like shell, I tried Git Bash on Windows.
- You use GNU sed.

Define this shell function in your profile or directly on the console:

```bash
git_log_branches() {
  git log --pretty=format:"commit %H%nAuthor:   %an <%ae>%nDate:     %ad%nBranches: %H%n%n%w(76,4,4)%B" "$@" |
    sed -E "s/^(Branches: )(.*)/echo -n '\1'; git branch --contains \2 --format='%(refname:short)' | tr '\n' ' '/e"
}
```

The log output would look something like this:

```
$ git_log_branches -2 HEAD~100
commit d81a845b61f5b98b217722122c6005cb51f9e160
Author:   Alexander Kriegisch <aaaa@bbb.xy>
Date:     Sun Jun 6 13:27:03 2021 +0700
Branches: main openj9-jit openj9-jit-exclude

    Integration test POM (group ID) + UML whitespace cosmetics

commit 25eafcc93340ee2ee6ce05d0ec1a2139e20d45d8
Author:   Florian Lasinger <ggg@hhh.yz>
Date:     Fri Feb 19 13:57:05 2021 +0100
Branches: main openj9-jit openj9-jit-exclude

    [#92] Dependency artifacts have higher precedence than reactor artifacts

    (cherry picked from commit f32367b3 + additional comment)
```

The output is not auto-paged. I do not like this solution much, but it is the best I could come up with, playing for a little while.

---

**Update:** Like *FelipeC* mentioned in his answer, of course you can also transform the shell function into a stand-alone shell script, name it *git-log-branches* and put it anywhere in your `PATH`, so Git can find it:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

git log --pretty=format:"commit %H%nAuthor:   %an <%ae>%nDate:     %ad%nBranches: %H%n%n%w(76,4,4)%B" "$@" |
  sed -E "s/^(Branches: )(.*)/echo -n '\1'; git branch --contains \2 --format='%(refname:short)' | tr '\n' ' '/e"
```

Then you call it with `git log-branches -2 HEAD~100` in order to get the exact same log output as above when calling the corresponding shell function.

---

I also compared log calls with regard to timing:

```
# OK, we have a history of 577 commits
$ git log --oneline | wc -l
577

# Generating a standard Git log is really quick!
$ time (git log | wc -l)
5471

real    0m0.100s

# As expected, kriegaex's solution is way slower. This is the
# price you pay if you want the branches for each commit.
$ time (git log-branches | wc -l)
6591

real    0m56.953s

# The performance of FelipeC's solution is in the same order of magnitude,
# just slightly slower. No big deal. Both solutions could be tweaked
# here or there.
$ time (git log-branches2 | wc -l)
6592

real    1m8.982s
```

---

**Update regarding `-G foo`:** When using `-G`, of course the filtering in Git as such takes most of the time, and the result are way fewer commits to process. Therefore, measuring overall performance - not talking about time to display the first hit here - does not really help. My measures above are more meaningful, because they affect **all** commits which would be processed in a log with more entries. But FWIW, now the numbers look like this:

```
$ time (git log -G foo --oneline | wc -l)
19

real    0m0.401s

$ time (git log-branches -G foo | wc -l)
216

real    0m2.683s

$ time (git log-branches2 -G foo | wc -l)
217

real    0m2.691s
```

Again, both solutions take similar amounts of time, but more than normal `git log`. No surprises here.

Now let us switch to a bigger OSS project - I chose Eclipse AspectJ - and search for `-G foo` there. Luckily, out of 8607 commits on the main branch, 707 contain "foo", i.e. not just a handful. So a performance measurement actually says something meaningful about the performance of the two scripts vs. Git itself:

```
# 8,607 commits in total
$ time (git log --oneline | wc -l)
8607

real    0m0.464s

# 707 commits contain "foo"
$ time (git log -G foo --oneline | wc -l)
707

real    0m55.196s

# Script by kriegaex
$ time (git log-branches -G foo | wc -l)
5450

real    1m15.749s

# Script by FelipeC
$ time (git log-branches2 -G foo | wc -l)
5451

real    1m19.283s
```

Here, we can see that of 75 (kriegaex) or 79 (FelipeC) seconds necessary to process all 707 commits, which really is quasi the same IMO, 55 seconds alone are used by Git to actually filter the big repository with 8,607 commits in the branch in question. I.e. 55/75 or 73,3% of the time is used by Git, and we are no longer comparing the actual script performance alone. The ratio would asymptotically creep up to 100%, the fewer commits are found by `-G`. This is why initially, I measured without the costly `-G` option, because it only pollutes the result.

Comment: a generic bash recomendation: double quote `"$@"` when you want to pass down a list of arguments

Comment: Good point. Like I said at the beginning of my answer, it is a quick & dirty solution rather than a sophisticated one. But I am going to update it.

Comment: Please note my update concerning how to call the script as a Git sub-command (thanks, _FelipeC_) and a performance comparison for both answers.

Comment: I updated the answer again, adding more logs and timings. Moreover, I adjusted the output formatting to FelipeC's solution in order to make it more easily comparable when diffing log files, which is what I did locally. E.g., now my log texts are also indented and my branch list is space-separated rather than comma-separated, even though I like the latter more. But now the scripts' outputs are in sync.

Comment: And one more update: I have come up with a best-of-both-worlds solution, performing as well as my original one when measuring overall execution time for all processed commits and enabling the output to be displayed commit by commit like _FelipeC_'s solution.

Comment: My original version (which I did not submit) did convert the output of `git log` commit by commit, but I didn't submit it because I found one with simpler code (and performance was never a requirement). I wrote a script that creates a repository to run tests and compares all the versions with 100 commits. Even your newer version is 1.6% slower than my original one.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the branches that contain said commits is to add `--simplify-by-decoration` :

```
# to make sense of how branches relate one to another :
git log --graph --oneline --simplify-by-decoration -G foo

# you can also add '-p' to see the content of selected commits, and you will see that
# the commits are not named individually

# to get just the ref names :
git log --format="%D" --simplify-by-decoration -G foo
```

The above commands will list any ref (local branches, remote branches, tags, `stash` ...) that appear in your history.
You can add [`--decorate-refs=refs/heads`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---decorate-refsltpatterngt) to list only local branches (or `--decorate-refs=whatever/suits/your/needs`).

---

[update]

I just found out `git log` has a [`--source`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---source) option (which has been around since version 1.6.1 ...) :

> **`--source`**
> Print out the ref name given on the command line by which each commit was reached.

So :

```
# to list local branches :
git log --branches -G foo

# or, to list remote branches :
git log -G foo $(git branch -r --format="%(refname:short)")
```

may give you interesting results.

Again, as noted by @kriegaex, this doesn't list *all* branches that contain each commit, it lets `git` select *one* branch name to be displayed, and this choice may not match your expectation.

By giving an explicit list of branches (or tags, or ...) to `git log`, you can narrow the list of names `git` can choose from.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. He wants all branches containing a commit.

Comment: @kriegax: I agree with the technical part of your statement. It also turns out that a commit is part of every branch that comes after it, so if a commit is old enough all the branches will be listed. Perhaps the OP may be interested in knowing that `git log` has a built-in feature that applies some filtering on the branches that are listed, rather than listing "is part of feature-33, feature-34, feature-35, .... feature-95". Note that the filtering isn't perfect either.